# TypeScript: Having difficulty typing a function that can filter on a specific level inside of an object while preserving its original structure

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object called `myCached` and its type is known as

```
interface MyCache {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: Target[];
      d: string;
    };
  };
}
```

Where `Target` is the type of the item in one of its property on a specific level, this type `Target` is known too. Assume `Target` is like this

```
type Target = "toRemove1" | "toRemove2" | "toPreserve1" | "toPreserve2";
```

In the example here, `myCache` is

```
const cache: MyCache = {
  a: {
    b: { 
      c: ['toRemove1', 'toPreserve1', 'toRemove2', 'toPreserve2'], 
      d: "irrelevant" 
    },
  }
}
```

And I have an array of items that I need to remove. They also have the type of `Target` as in

```
const thingsToRemove: Target[] = ["toRemove1", "toRemove2"];
```

And I am trying to come up with a function that can traverse this object and filter out items on a specific level. The way I designed this function is that it takes a transformer object and it travers the object and it provides the function for filtering. I want to type it properly so the users of this function can reply on the auto complete provided by the TS compiler and type checking to make sure that this function lands correctly on the correct level, in this case it is the `Target` level.

This is my code

```
type MappedTransform<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: MappedTransform<T[K]> | ((params: T[K]) => T[K]);
};

type Entries<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T];

function traverse<R>(cache: R, transformObject: MappedTransform<R>): R {
  return (Object.entries(transformObject) as Array<
    Entries<MappedTransform<R>>
  >).reduce(reduceTransformNode, cache);
}

const reduceTransformNode = <R, K extends keyof R>(
  cacheNode: R,
  [transformKey, transformValue]: [
    K,
    MappedTransform<R[K]> | ((params: R[K]) => R[K]) | undefined
  ]
): R => {
  const { [transformKey]: node } = cacheNode;

  if (typeof transformValue === "undefined") return cacheNode;

  const newCacheValue =
    typeof transformValue === "function"
      ? (transformValue as (params: R[K]) => R[K])(node)
      : traverse(transformValue as R[K], node);

  return {
    ...cacheNode,
    [transformKey]: newCacheValue
  };
};

const x = traverse(cache, {
  a: {
    b: {
      // Need to use Type `Target` to make sure that the transformer function lands on the type of `Target` exactly
      c: (node) => node.filter((s) => !thingsToRemove.includes(s))
    }
  }
});
```

This works fine and I have been really close to what I wanted to achieve except that **I cannot seem to find a way to add the type of `Target` to make sure that the function the user provides to do the filtering actually is on the right level i.e. `node` is of the right type `Target`**

Here is the [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/superhardts-116bf?file=/src/index.ts). Can someone tell me how to achieve that last bit of type safety I am seeking for here?